# How can I use Javascript or CSS to hover a button and have a div scroll right or left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to create a photo gallery with a block for the description below it. I would also like to have two buttons, one on either side of the photos. When you hover over these buttons (likely arrows), I would like the div containing the photos to scroll (or appear to scroll) either right or left. I have looked into a few JSFiddles, but none of them do exactly what I would like. [This one](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xmAvh/) comes close, but I want it to scroll left and right, rather than up and down. I tried the code with my div, but it didn't do anything. This is the page I'm working with:

**[website is no longer in existence]**

Thanks in advance!

```
var amount = '';

function scroll() {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 100, 'linear',function() {
        if (amount != '') {
            scroll();
        }
    });
}
$('#hover').hover(function() {
    amount = '+=10';
    scroll();
}, function() {
    amount = '';
});
$('#hover2').hover(function() {
    amount = '-=10';
    scroll();
}, function() {
    amount = '';
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the scroll function, you want to set  "scrollLeft"

I've created a fiddle, that I think does what you are looking to do.  I've put the text into another div so that it won't automatically wrap to the width of it's primary container.

```
function scroll() {
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollLeft: amount
    }, 100, 'linear',function() {
        if (amount != '') {
            scroll();
        }
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXCpC/1/)

Comment: That's perfect, but can you tell me how to keep the <ul> from dropping down like it is now? I want to try to get the buttons on the same line as the photos. For some reason the javascript isn't working either.

Comment: I assume you're looking at the original URL.  Make the div - photosContainer float left and then put it above the navigation IMGs.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks much! I had a typo in my CSS. Everything's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Change

```
 $('#container').animate({
    scrollUp: amount
}, 100, 'linear',function() {
    if (amount != '') {
        scroll();
    }
});
```

to

```
 $('#container').animate({
    scrollLeft: amount
}, 100, 'linear',function() {
    if (amount != '') {
        scroll();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmAvh/21/)